# Subset from a list

Tags: r

I have a list that looks like this:

```
 cse[[1]]   
 [1] "name1"  "surname1"    
 cse[[2]] 
 [1] "name2"  "surname2"
 cse[[3]] 
 [1] "name3"  "surname3"    
 ......................     
 cse[[92514]]
```

How can I subset only the elements corresponding to:

```
cse[[1]][1]    
cse[[2]][1]   
cse[[3]][1]    
...........    
cse[[92514]]
```

corresponding to: name1, name2, name3, ...,  and put them together in a data.frame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
sapply(cse, "[", 1)
```